# ConcurrentHashMap method execution order in multithreaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

As per the below JLS rule-
Each action in a thread happens-before every action in that thread that comes later in the program's order.

In the below case, would clear() always execute before put in a multithreaded environment

```
private ConcurrentMap<Feature, Boolean> featureMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public void loadAllConfiguration() {
    featureMap.clear();
    featureMap.put()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the below case, would clear() always execute before put in a multithreaded environment

Yes, in a multithreaded application, in each thread `clear()` comes before `put()`.  However when you look at the interaction of *multiple* threads then this is no longer true in terms of the shared `ConcurrentHashMap`.

For example, due to race conditions, you might see the following sequence of events:

1. Thread 1 calls clear().
2. Thread 2 calls clear().
3. Thread 3 calls clear().
4. Thread 2 calls put().
5. Thread 1 calls put().
6. Thread 3 calls put().

Even though each thread does clear and then put, there is no guarantee that there will only be 1 item in the `ConcurrentHashMap` if that was the point of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super clear on the question but I think:

> Each action in a thread happens-before every action in that thread
>   that comes later in the program's order.

Means that within the context of a single thread (since `clear` and `put` are blocking synchronous calls) that the runtime guarantees that they will be executed in the order they are invoked.

Based on my limited understanding of java, this should NOT extend to a multithreaded environment.  Suppose you have a single concurrent map shared between two threads, and each one of those threads invokes `loadAllConfiguration` against a shared `featureMap`.

The threads can be executed concurrently, so that the operations are interleved!!!!

This could result in an execution order of:

```
**THREAD 1**                          **THREAD 2**
map.clear()
map.put()
                                     map.clear()
                                     map.put()
```

or even in both clears being called concurrently and then both puts being applied concurrently.

---

I haven't used java so i'm not sure what the [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) provides, but i'm assuming that it only protects you from race conditions (one thread writing while another reads) by using some sort of synchronization, but it should still might leave you exposed to logical errors (ie clears/put) being interleaved in a deterministic way)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understand that the execution order will be guaranteed in the context of a single thread